# IControllerFactory was found in the resolver - System.InvalidOperationException thrown

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have encountered a strange behavior in vs2012 utilmate, C#, and MVC 4.0 on Win7 os.

Error:
"An instance of IControllerFactory was found in the resolver as well as a custom registered provider in ControllerBuilder.GetControllerFactory. Please set only one or the other."

Source Error: 
 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 
[InvalidOperationException: An instance of IControllerFactory was found in the resolver as well as a custom registered provider in ControllerBuilder.GetControllerFactory. Please set only one or the other.]
   System.Web.Mvc.SingleServiceResolver`1.GetValueFromResolver() +960077
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +455
   System.Lazy`1.get_Value() +14443978
   System.Web.Mvc.SingleServiceResolver`1.get_Current() +20
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.GetSessionStateBehavior(RequestContext requestContext) +152
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) +46
   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context) +12673415
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165

I'm not able to enter the site. The site is completely un-navigable. First entering the url for the default page throws the error.

I'm able to set and break at a breakpoint within Global.asax Application_BeginRequest method.Stepping through Application_BeginRequest method doesn't cause error, however leaving Application_BeginRequest and navigating to the Login page, the Login page responds with a 500 error.

Setting breakpoints within the Login page's methods, I wasn't able to break.

I believe the error is happening on the Login page, but I'm really not clear on where.

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
deDogs

Comment: Are you using any IoC?

Comment: Thank you Ramunas - yes I'm using IoC.

Comment: That depends on IoC itself and the way how you've setup your registrations. But basically error message says that you have registered your IoC driven Controller factory in two places and you should use only one. Which IoC do you use?